# Real time process missing deadline with SCHED_RR

Tags: real-time, embedded-linux, scheduler

I have below configs on ARMv7 embedded OMAP system.
sched_rt_period_us = 1000000 = 1 sec
sched_rt_runtime_us = 950000 = 0.95 sec

And i have 4 Real time processes running with SCHED_RR and pri = 1 
and sched_rr_get_interval () returned 93750000 nanosec, i.e.  0.093750 sec on system.

I have added a new process with SCHED_RR and pri of 1 and same default rr_interval 
of 0.09375 sec.

According to this configs:
On every second 5 RT processes must execute 2 times each (0.09375 * 10 = 0.9375 sec) and 
rest of the time interval of 1 Sec is to be used by non-RT tasks 
i.e.,  1.0 - 0.9375 = 0.0625 Sec.

But as i see from execution the 5th newly added task misses the timeline and only executes randomly and produces output every 1 sec or indeterminate. Please help me on how to make 
this new process deterministic so that it executes twice per sec as per above configs.

I tried to configure static pri of 2 and also checked with SCHED_FIFO but got the same 
results.

Or is there anything i am missing in these calculations.

I am using :
Linux xxxx 2.6.33 #2 PREEMPT Tue Aug 14 16:13:05 CEST 2012 armv7l GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the scheduler does not fail because it is not able to honor the scheduling requests? I mean, that fifth task doesn't meet the deadline because the system is too heavily loaded?

As far as I know, sched_setscheduler does not have a way to signal that the system load is too heavy. To know if the system is able to meet the request, you need another scheduling algorithm, such as [edf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earliest_deadline_first_scheduling). Maybe you want to check its implementation for [linux](https://github.com/jlelli/sched-deadline/wiki).